# My cmake can't find Visual Studtio 2015 automatically

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015

Tried to find it by using option "Specify native compiler", but cannot find what's the file name for VS2015.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SO! Please try to formulate a specific question (such as "what's the file name to specify to cmake for VS2015?")

Comment: You are calling CMake from Visual Studio or from a command window outside? For the latter, use vcvarsall.bat. If this does not help, you might want to define the build tool chain using `-G "Visual Studio <version>"`